# Where should the circuit breaker go?

Tags: api-design, microservices, architectural-patterns

I'm developing a new REST API and I've seen some projects place the circuit breaker in the `Controller`. I used to place it in the `DAO`.

First difference I can say is that placing it in the `DAO` is that every service which consume this third party will be open in the error scenario. And placing it in the `Controller`, would EVENTUALLY open every route that consumes this third party; so it won't be immediately. But the second choice (in the `Controller`) seems easier to mantain.

Any recommendation about where should it go?

Comment: According to [this](https://microservices.io/patterns/reliability/circuit-breaker.html), it belongs in your [API Gateway](https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html).

Comment: Yes, I understand it should go in the API Gateway, but you can consume an API Gateway with a circuit breaker too. Or maybe you are the API Gateway. The question goes deeper, inside the own code, in which package it should be written. Perhaps, interpreting the API Gateway as a DAO (the only way to access the third party) in the code, would end up choosing the first option.

Comment: There's a code sample in [this article](https://microservices.io/patterns/reliability/circuit-breaker.html).  It points to a complete sample application [here](https://github.com/cer/microservices-examples).  That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: A gateway to an external system (w/ respect to whatever you define your own "system box" to be) is just some component that you own that acts as a Facade to an external system (i.e., it's a more general concept than an API Gateway in this sense, which is just a version of it that's distributed separately, and possibly shared). A circuit breaker in a gateway ensures that you are well-behaved as *a client*. A circuit breaker in a controller seems to be more about protecting you, acting now as *a server*; this may be more relevant when clients are beyond your control or influence (3rd party).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts in this answer.  The first part was already addressed by [Robert Harvey](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1204/robert-harvey) in his comment:

- According to Chris Richardson's catalogue of microservices patterns, the [circuit breaker](https://microservices.io/patterns/reliability/circuit-breaker.html) should be in a proxy for the remote service. The API Gateway is a good place for it.
- Another alternative it the server-side discovery,  especially if the recovery strategy implies finding other running instances of the same service.

But there is a second part. The goal of the circuit breaker is to fail fast if service is detected to be unavailable, instead of accumulating steps that will fail later creating a lot of frustration.  So the circuit-breaker gets its full sense only if the consuming service is ready to react to the break:

- Maybe the remote service is essential,  and the consuming service could decide to put itself on hold (i.e. internal circuit breaker).
- May be the remote service is not essential, and the consuming service could decide to continue to serve, but in a degraded mode.
- (service discovery based breakers will probably not fail but find another working service and the consumers will not notice).

From the general point of view, this kind of choices in the behavior is a controller responsibility:  the controller coordinates between the elements of the service, and is able to adapt the processing based on the "fail" information.

However, if in your case, it is only about getting data from elsewhere and if your error processing strategy is always the same (no difference between essential and non-essential;  for example try to use a cached value if available and fail otherwhise) you could perfectly well decide to put it in the dao imho.